# PayPal IPN no almacena en MySql

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

Estoy teniendo problemas con el `IPN` de `PayPal`, es mi primera vez integrando esta pasarela y los datos que vienen en la documentación se me hicieron un poco revueltos.

cree 3 archivos para poder procesar el pago, `paquetes` `ipn` y `success`.

No estoy usando los botones por lo que cree variables para el formulario que se manda a `PayPal` que se encuentra en paquetes

```
<?php

$loggedUser = $_SESSION["id"];

$date = getdate();

$day = $date["mday"];
$month = $date["mon"];
$year = $date["year"];

//PayPal variables
$paypalURL     = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$paypalID     = 'facilitator@hotmail.com';
$successURL = 'http://prueba.com/success';
$cancelURL     = 'http://prueba.com/cancel';
$notifyURL     = 'http://prueba.com/paypal_ipn';

$itemName = 'Suscripcion 1!';
$itemName2 = 'Suscripcion 2!';
$itemName3 = 'Suscripcion 3!';
$itemNumber = 'MS/'.$day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year.'/'.$loggedUser;

//subscription price for one month
$itemPrice = 0.02;
```

y asi es como resulta el formulario que viene siendo el boton creado por mi asignandole las variables

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">
        <!-- identify your business so that you can collect the payments -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">
        <!-- specify a subscriptions button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
        <!-- specify details about the subscription that buyers will purchase -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="MXN">
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="paypalAmt" value="<?php echo $itemPrice; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" id="paypalValid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
        <!-- custom variable user ID -->
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $loggedUser; ?>">
        <!-- specify urls -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $cancelURL; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $successURL; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $notifyURL; ?>">
        <!-- display the payment button -->
        <input class="paypal_button" type="submit" value="Comprar Suscripción">
</form>
```

todo se envia correctamente a `PayPal` pero al momento de que se deberia devolver los datos en `ipn` y `success` lo unico que se recibe por get es lo siquiente

```
http://exampledomain.com/success?auth=AwayQdhjzADAexJ4X-hVqtlSrIzEW1KUFaLNIMlJg8Qhd6LkVXizKvsoahKvZkQN4xe1MjohmDqn3NaFS-lTsBQ&form_charset=UTF-8
```

en ipn tengo los datos de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

/*
 * Read POST data
 * reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
 * issues with array data in POST.
 * Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
 */        
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

// Read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

/*
 * Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
 * Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
 */
$paypalURL = "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$ch = curl_init($paypalURL);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);

/*
 * Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
 * Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
 */ 
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 || strcasecmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    //Include DB configuration file
    //Database credentials
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'User';
    $dbPassword = 'Pass';
    $dbName = 'Name';

    //Connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    //Display error if failed to connect
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $unitPrice = 25;

    //Payment data
    $subscrid = $_POST['subscr_id'];
    $payerwemail = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $itemnumber = $_POST['item_number'];
    $txnid = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $paymentgross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $currencycode = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    $subscrmonth = ($payment_gross/$unitPrice);
    $subscrdays = ($subscr_month*30);
    $subscrdate_from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $subscrdateto = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($subscrdatefrom. ' + '.$subscrdays.' days'));

    if(!empty($txn_id)){
        //Check if subscription data exists with the same TXN ID.
        $prevPayment = $db->query("SELECT id FROM usersubscriptions WHERE txnid = '".$txnid."'");
        if($prevPayment->num_rows > 0){
            exit();
        }else{
            //Insert tansaction data into the database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO usersubscriptions(userid,validity,validfrom,validto,itemnumber,txnid,paymentgross,currencycode,subscrid,paymentstatus,payerwemail) VALUES('".$custom."','".$subscrmonth."','".$subscrdatefrom."','".$subscrdateto."','".$itemnumber."','".$txnid."','".$paymentgross."','".$currencycode."','".$subscrid."','".$paymentstatus."','".$payerwemail."')");

            //Update subscription id in users table
            if($insert){
                $subscriptionid = $db->insertid;
                $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET subscriptionid = {$subscriptionid} WHERE id = {$custom}");
            }
        }
    }
}
die;
```

se que tengo vulnerabilidad a una inyección SQL pero ese no es el problema puesto que por obvias razones cambiare todo a PDO

y en success tengo lo siguiente

```
<?php
//Include DB configuration file
include 'dbconnect.php';

if(!empty($_GET['item_number']) && !empty($_GET['tx']) && !empty($_GET['amt']) && $_GET['st'] == 'Completed'){
    //get transaction information from query string
    $item_number = $_GET['item_number'];
    $txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
    $payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
    $currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
    $payment_status = $_GET['st'];
    $custom = $_GET['cm'];

    //Check if subscription data exists with the TXN ID
    $prevPaymentResult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usersubscriptions WHERE txnid = '".$txn_id."'");

    if($prevPaymentResult->num_rows > 0){
        //get subscription info from database
        $paymentRow = $prevPaymentResult->fetch_assoc();

        //prepare subscription html to display
        $phtml  = '<h5 class="success">Thanks for payment, your payment was successful. Payment details are given below.</h5>';
        $phtml .= '<div class="paymentInfo">';
        $phtml .= '<p>Payment Reference Number: <span>MS'.$paymentRow['id'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '<p>Transaction ID: <span>'.$paymentRow['txn_id'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '<p>Paid Amount: <span>'.$paymentRow['payment_gross'].' '.$paymentRow['currency_code'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '<p>Validity: <span>'.$paymentRow['valid_from'].' to '.$paymentRow['valid_to'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '</div>';
    }else{
        $phtml = '<h5 class="error">Your payment was unsuccessful, please try again.</h5>';
    }
}elseif(!empty($_GET['item_number']) && !empty($_GET['tx']) && !empty($_GET['amt']) && $_GET['st'] != 'Completed'){
    $phtml = '<h5 class="error">Your payment was unsuccessful, please try again.</h5>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PayPal Subscriptions Payment Payment Status</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>PayPal Subscriptions Payment Status</h1>
    <!-- render subscription details -->
    <?php echo !empty($phtml)?$phtml:''; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

he cambiado el cogido una y otra vez y sigue sin funcionar, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a saber en que estoy mal o que código debe llevar para que pueda insertar los datos en la base de datos

> Nuevo codigo y error

En ipn cambie todos los valores por lo siguiente

```
<?php

$nombre = $_SESSION["name"];
$apellido = $_SESSION["lastname"];
$nombreCompleto = $nombre.' '.$apellido;

$subscr_date_from = $this->issetCheck($post,'subscr_date');
$subscr_days = 30;
$subscr_date_to = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($subscr_date_from. ' + '.$subscr_days.' days'));

class PayPal_IPN{
    function infotuts_ipn($im_debut_ipn) {

        define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
            $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
            if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
                // mail test
            }

            return false;
        }

        // parse the paypal URL
        $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
        $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

        $post_string = '';
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
            $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
        }
        $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
        // get the correct paypal url to post request to
        $paypal_mode_status = $im_debut_ipn; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
        if ($paypal_mode_status == true){
            $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
        } else{
            $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
        }

        $ipn_response = '';

        if (!$fp) {
            // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
            // will be in the log.
            $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
            if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
                echo 'fsockopen fail';
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            // Post the data back to paypal
            fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

            // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
            fclose($fp); // close connection
        }

        // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
        if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
            $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

            if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
                echo 'Validation fail';
                print_r($_REQUEST);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
            if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
                echo 'SUCCESS';

                }

            return true;
        }
    }

    function ipn_response($request){
        mail("clientes@dominio.com","My subject",print_r($request,true));
        $im_debut_ipn=true;
        if ($this->infotuts_ipn($im_debut_ipn)) {

            // if paypal sends a response code back let's handle it        
               if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
                $sub = 'PayPal IPN Debug Email Main';
                $msg = print_r($request, true);
                $aname = 'infotuts';
              //mail send
            }

            // process the membership since paypal gave us a valid +
            $this->insert_data($request);
        }
    }

    function issetCheck($post,$key){
        if(isset($post[$key])){
            $return=$post[$key];
        } else {
            $return='';
        }
        return $return;
    }

    function insert_data($request){
        require_once('dbconnect.php');
        $post=$request;

        $datos = array(
            $idUser = $_SESSION["id"],
            $suscriptorId = $this->issetCheck($post,'subscr_id'),
            $name = $nombreCompleto,
            $nombrePlan = $this->issetCheck($post,'item_name'),
            $payerStatus = $this->issetCheck($post,'payer_status'),
            $payer_email = $this->issetCheck($post,'payer_email'),
            $payerId = $this->issetCheck($post,'payer_id'),
            $cantidad = $this->issetCheck($post,'mc_amount3'),
            $periodo = $this->issetCheck($post,'period3'),
            $diaSuscripcion = $this->issetCheck($post,'subscr_date'),
            $finalizaEn = $subscr_date_to,
            $autorizacion = $this->issetCheck($post,'auth')
        );

        $respuestaPago = ControladorPago::ctrCrearPago($datos);

        if ($respuestaPago = "ok") {
            $phtml = '<h5 class="error">Tu pago se ha generado correctamente.</h5>';
        } else {
            echo "eror";
        }
    }

    $obj = New PayPal_IPN();
    $obj -> ipn_response($_REQUEST);
}

?>
```

y el error que me marca en el log que crea mi host es el siguiente

```
[11-Jul-2018 20:32:12 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$obj' 
(T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in 
/home/ntkoeqcqx3ss/prueba/vista/modulos/ipn.php on line 144
```

Comment: Chequee el código de ejemplo implementado por PayPal [aquí](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php), cualquier nueva duda, actualice su pregunta.

Comment: @wchiquito vi la documentacion y ahora tengo un nuevo error, acabo de actualizar mi pregunta con los nuevos datos, espero me puedas ayuar

Comment: El nuevo error no está relacionado directamente con IPN-PayPal, es un error relacionado con la variable `$obj` y el intento de instanciar la clase `PayPal_IPN`. Verifique [`example_usage.php`](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage.php) para un ejemplo de uso.